# PNP js version 3 get sp object return a Proxy object

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnpjs

I create a SPFX with PNP JS version 3, when I try to get the sp object , it return a Proxy object. I try to use the getSP() function in the official demo , same result.

```
getItems() {
    //
    const _sp = getSP();
    const response:SPFI = spfi().using(SPFx(this.context))//.web.lists.getByTitle("511").items.select("Title");
    // const response=await spfi(_sp).using(Caching({ store: "session" })).web.lists.getByTitle("511").items.select("Title")
    console.log(response.web);
    
  }
```

[image]

Do you know why and how to deal with it?Thank you！

Answer (score 0):

try this,
it works for me.

```
private async _bindMonths() {
   const _sp = getSP();
   await spfi(_sp).web.lists.getByTitle("511").items().then(rslt => {
     console.log(rslt);
   }).catch(error => {
     console.log(error)
  })
}
```